# Error building Shoutem preview build after modifying extension

Tags: shoutem

I've working on modification of the '*shoutem.notification-center*' extension using as a guide this [tutorial](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions) and I'm having some issues.

At first I tried to use the **Extend the extension** approach, but like I've posted on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001157/shoutem-modifying-extensions), didn't quite work.

So I've tried the **Directly modify** approach, which works fine on my local phone, but once I use the command `shoutem push` to send my modifications to the server, the instance on Appetize never stops the 'Building your application' message.
The major problem is that there's no error code or feedback.

That was not the first time that happened, I had the same issue modifying other extensions. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely one of two things.

1. New native dependencies were added that the Builder preview cannot process due to it's predefined binary.
2. Your directly modified extension works locally, but not on the Builder because locally it's path is still `AppName/extensions/shoutem.extName`, but on the Builder it's `AppName/extensions/yourDevName.extName`, so it fails.

The first one can be resolved by either using a non-native solution as a replacement for the native dependency you were using, or to simply use a local emulator for previewing purposes.

The second can be resolved by making sure all extensions that reference the one you directly modified are edited to now reference your new directly modified extension instead of `shoutem.extName`.

If you could shoot me your app ID in a comment I can let you know which one it is and what the best steps to fix it would be.

Comment: Thank a lot! It was the second case, the extension name on the server. Changing the name on the "app/package.json" and "server/package.json" solved the issue!